# Handling CORS for API that serving ajax call and server to server calls

Tags: ajax, cors

I'm building an endpoint (let say `/v1/getdata`). This endpoint will serve a call from both ajax and server to server. Since this endpoint has different origin than the website that will use it (lets say `http://www.t.com`), i need to implement a CORS for ajax call. I know i must add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to response whenever the request has `http://www.t.com` in it's `Origin` header, so the browser will accept ajax call from cross origin.

But server to server call doesn't send `Origin` header. What is the best approach for this? Should i add `Origin` header manually into the request from server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making the API public, then you can simply add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to all responses.

If you are making it available to only certain sites, then the logic you should use is:

```
Is the Origin request header present?
    If not, don't add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header
Is the Origin one that is on your whitelist of acceptable sites?
    If not, don't add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header
    Otherwise, add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header 
               with a value that matches the Origin request header
```